# Por que aparece este "error"

Tags: javascript, php, warnings

Buen dia , despues de años de utilizar un sistema, bueno resulta que estoy actualizando algunas funciones, interfaz etc..

Y de buenas a primeras me esta enviando este error en la consola:

```js
no es posible revisar <input pattern='(^[A-Z]{1}[AEIOU]{1}[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])[HM]{1}(AS|BC|BS|CC|CS|CH|CL|CM|DF|DG|GT|GR|HG|JC|MC|MN|MS|NT|NL|OC|PL|QT|QR|SP|SL|SR|TC|TS|TL|VZ|YN|ZS|NE)[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{3}[0-9A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}?$'> porque regexpl no es una patente válida: unterminated parenthetical
```

y en el phpstorm en una funcion me señala lo siguiente:

```js
function isCurp(e){ 
    var for_curp=/(^[A-Z]{1}[AEIOU]{1}[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])[HM]{1}(AS|BC|BS|CC|CS|CH|CL|CM|DF|DG|GT|GR|HG|JC|MC|MN|MS|NT|NL|OC|PL|QT|QR|SP|SL|SR|TC|TS|TL|VZ|YN|ZS|NE)[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{3}[0-9A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}$)/;
    curp=document.getElementById('CURP').value ;
    if(for_curp.test(curp))
    { document.getElementById('CURP_COR').innerHTML='<b>CURP CORRECTA</b>'; }  <<-- Unescapedxml caracter 
    else 
    { document.getElementById('CURP_COR').innerHTML='<b>CURP INVALIDA&lt;</b>'; }   <<-- Unescapedxml  caracter 
    }
```

haber si me pueden explicar a que se deben estos "warnigs".

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a cambiar el atributo `pattern` del input y añadele `/` tanto al incio como al final de la [`regular-expression`](https://regexr.com/) tal que:

```
<input pattern='/(^[A-Z]{1}[AEIOU]{1}[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])[HM]{1}(AS|BC|BS|CC|CS|CH|CL|CM|DF|DG|GT|GR|HG|JC|MC|MN|MS|NT|NL|OC|PL|QT|QR|SP|SL|SR|TC|TS|TL|VZ|YN|ZS|NE)[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{3}[0-9A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}?$/'>
```

Comment: Fernandez Flores   Gracias por el aporte , apenas lo leí hoy 26052022, solo agrege al inicio y al final paréntesis, cambie las comillas dobles por sencillas y con esto dejo de señalar ese error,  donde me marcaba el otro error actualice la función por otra, pero al final ni siquiera hace la acción señalada.